# rotated image in rviz when using kinect

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
While using kinect and viewing image I'm getting 90 degree rotated image. What I'm saying is instead of top to bottom, rviz shows left side of image on top and right part of image as bottom so it looks lik its rotated 90degree.

what shld i do to get to usual image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32793/rotated-image-in-rviz-when-using-kinect/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) on 2012-04-26**:
can u post the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Just change the tf frame in the Fixed frame of rviz. It should work. If it doesn't please post the image here.

Hope it helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-05-02**:
I'm not able to post the image files...how to do it?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-02**:
please use online sharing site for sharing the images... you may use dropbox.com

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-05-02**:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77103934/Screenshot%20at%202012-05-02%2022%3A20%3A29.png

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-05-02**:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/77103934/Screenshot%20at%202012-05-02%2022%3A22%3A00.png    these two pics will show rviz image and corresponding image for the command rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color. why do i get rviz output like this?

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-02**:
could you set the background to black and add Grid in the rviz for the pointcloud image and send the screenshot again

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-05-02**:
please add tf also to the rviz so that the tf frames are seen in the display

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-05-03**:
I'm not able to launch openni i'm getting error as

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-05-03**:
nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr::reference boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo, boost::shared_ptr::reference = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 8176, exit code -6]